# Work around with Delphi DLL

Tags: delphi

I have two applications in Delphi for which I don't have any code source:

I use an interface from application A to call an DLL file from application B. Example, I usually pass a service number, 200011, from interface A to call DLL file B for a value return. But, recently the application A have changed the variable. I have to add P00200011 to call DLL file B.

I have tried to create an DLL C#, but the DLL in B is created with the [fastcall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#fastcall) convention and I cannot change this DLL file.

What are others ways I can do it? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: This question is rather unintelligible. Pleas try to make it clear what you are asking. What I would say is that `fastcall` is an MSVC calling convention. Do you perhaps mean Delphi `register` convention?

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a wrapper DLL. You build your DLL with the functions you want to intercept, and in your code you simply load and call the original DLL. Then you place your wrapper in the same directory of your application. All calls from the application will go to your wrapper DLL and from there to the original DLL.

Here is a simple example

supose you have this library (B.DLL)

```
library B;
function B_FUNCTION(value:integer): integer; export;
 begin
  result:=value+1;
 end;
exports B_FUNCTION;
end.
```

And this program that uses it

```
program A;
{$apptype console}
function B_FUNCTION(value:integer): integer; external 'b.dll';
var i:integer;
begin
  i:=B_FUNCTION(2010);
  writeln(i);
end.
```

Compile both programs and run them. The result printed is 2011.

Now, code your wrapper DLL

```
library w;
uses windows;
function B_FUNCTION(value:integer): integer; export;
 var 
  adll: Thandle;
  afunc: function(v:integer):integer;
 begin
  adll:=LoadLibrary('TRUE_B.DLL');
  afunc:= GetProcAddress(adll,'B_FUNCTION');
  result:=afunc(value+1);
  FreeLibrary(adll);
 end;
exports B_FUNCTION; 
end.
```

Build it, you'll have A.EXE, B.DLL and W.DLL. Replace them

```
REN B.DLL TRUE_B.DLL
REN W.DLL B.DLL
```

Execute A, now it will spit 2012.

Comment: You need to address the issue of calling convention. And export is not needed. It does nothing.

Comment: There is no need to calling conversion, because the wrapper dll is also written in Delphi. Also export is needed because the wrapper dll is sitting in place of A.DLL and must have the same functions of A.DLL. But the problem is wrapping A.DLL will not solve the problem! You should wrap B.DLL instead.

Comment: Hi, what i can do if i cannot use Delphi to create wrapper DLL

Comment: @vahid you are right! I should wrap B and not A!! edited and fixed, thanks.

Comment: @user Why can't you use it? I am not sure that you can reproduce Delphi default calling convention (somewhere called fastcall and somewhere called register) without Delphi. One alternative that could possibly work is Free Pascal.

Comment: Hi, problem that i cannot replace REN W.DLL B.DLL cuz i need B.dll , i only need to wrapping one function in B.dll through my W.dll

Comment: In fact, my problem is how to create a W.dll calling B.dll both in delphi and only modify one parameter from one function of B.dll

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely obvious to me which parts are yours and what calls what, but you should be able to create your own intermediate DLL in Delphi with an interface that uses fastcall and which forwards the call to the real DLL using another calling convention.

Comment: I have to create an intermediate DLL without Delphi what else can i use to create intermediate DLL?